# How to convert Vmware Fusion virtual machine to bootcamp image

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp, vmware

i'm using ENVI + IDL software on a windows xp virtual machine. That software is too heavy so i can't work as well on that virtual machine so i need to boot that virtual machine on boot so to have all cpu and memory allocated for windows. Is there something could i do? Thanks!!

Comment: Can't you install Windows from the original media using the Bootcamp Assistant?

Comment: my problem is that i no longer have ENVI installation disk so i need to use only that virtual machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting a VM to a Bootcamp image is not supported and is technically difficult for a number of reasons, not least of which is that a Windows installation for a VM (or any physical computer) will not necessarily have all the drivers needed to run on different hardware.  There are other twitchy things about Windows like the whole license activation thing which tend to get in the way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although not conventional - you could use a DR (disaster recovery) imaging tool (ie StorageCraft), create a disk-level image backup and save to an external drive, then you would boot from the imaging tool's bootable software on a USB stick and restore it to a bootcamp partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open your VM in Parallels. Parallels has a feature that lets you boot your VM in Bootcamp.

I have not done this myself; you'll have to do further research to verify.

Comment: It's actually the other way round - Parallels allows you to use your Boot Camp partition like a VM.